# Does React.lazy() require webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, code-splitting

I was reading the docs on [`React.lazy()`](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) and it wasn't clear to me whether using that API requires me to use a module bundler that supports that syntax.

What if I am not using any bundler and just using `<script type="module" src="example.mjs"></script>` to provide modules, will `React.lazy()` still work and does it even make sense to do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without bundler `React.lazy` will not work because it depends on dynamic imports.
Dynamic imports it is not a feature that browsers support for now(it is ecmascript [proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-dynamic-import)), but bundlers do.
So answer is yes. Read more about [dynamic imports](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/#dynamic-imports) in webpack.